# Local machine web developing - macOS

Tags: macos, file, local

I was trying to mock up a web page flow on my local machine and was using local file links to give an idea of how the pages would flow.
So basically all the hrefs would direct to a local file on my machine. However, Safari doesn't seem to like that and prevents me from accessing any local file: "Not allowed to load local resource" even after I've disabled local file restrictions from the Develop menu.
Is there any way around this? All my files will be local so there really shouldn't be a security issue here.

Comment: What is your macOS version?